# How far can an object literal be nested?

Tags: javascript, oop, properties, nested, object-literal

I have found that it is possible to nest another property within an object literal property. Here is an example of this:

```
var rectangle = { 
    upperLeft : { x : 2, y : 2 },
    lowerRight : { x : 4, y : 4}
};
```

However, when I tried to nest yet another property within that nested property, I could not get this to work. Is maybe my syntax incorrect? Here is my code:

```
var rectangle = { 
    upperLeft : { x : {min: 2, max: 4}, y : 2 },
    lowerRight : { x : {min: 4, max: 6}, y : 4}
};
```

Comment: Your syntax is correct. What does "I could not get this to work" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second sample is fine. When you access:

```
rectangle.upperLeft.x.min
```

it correctly returns `2`. What problems do you encounter? Note that there is no theoretical maximum nesting level.

Comment: Oops, my mistake -- my testing of this code was incorrect, thanks.