# JavaScript Functional Reference Depth Limit

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is any functional depth limit to JavaScript. I'm asking because I'm working on a complex application and unfortunately, we cannot change the data structure.

For example, if I try to reference a variable such as:

`Thi.sIs.An.Except.ionally[345].LongF.unct.ional[z].Refer.ence.Thats[23].Sev.eral.Lay.ers[96].Deep`

I can sometimes set and get the value of the `Deep` struct and its members if it's in the same window, but if I include this element in another class or attempt to reference it from another page and set Deep's members, then deep later returns null or undefined for each of its members. The browser doesn't throw an error, I just get unexpected behavior.

Edit: I want to add, I am trying to reference `Deep` from a nested frame at least three levels down on the same domain.  For example, the frame would need to reference `Deep` in frame `Course`, two layers down from the main frame, but on a seperate branch from the frame that needs to acess it. The application we inherited uses frames, but these can be changed to iframes. Would changing these to iframes also work?

```
parent.Topic.Course.Thi.sIs.An.Except.ionally[345].LongF.unct.ional[z].Refer.ence.Thats[23].Sev.eral.Lay.ers[96].Deep
```

Is there something that I'm missing here? Or some sort of reference for JavaScript functional depth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How far can an object literal be nested?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604995/how-far-can-an-object-literal-be-nested)

Comment: @ChristianVarga that is a crappy dupe you linked to. The answer is basically a question.

Comment: *"attempt to reference it from another page"* Another page as in Pop Up window or Iframe?

Comment: @epascarello The question asked about a maximum nesting level, and the answer in my comment states there is no maximum nesting level. If that's not a direct answer to a direct question, I don't know what is.

Comment: @epascarello - I still don't like that question as a dupe.  One person's unsupported comment that "there is no maximum level" should not be taken as global fact across all JS implementations, even if it is correct (I have no idea).  I tested it in chrome and it's at least 1 million, but that doesn't mean infinite.

For the purposes of this question, and that the other one was basically closed with "your code works" with no further discussion, I don't think this is a dupe.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies, I added some more code, where I am attempting to reference `Deep` from another frame several frames deep within the same domain, on the same server.

Comment: @cwolves: That's kind of like asking "What's the largest array size I can allocate in Javascript"? It should depend on the memory available, not on any particular implementation design detail.

Comment: I think the problem here is iframes and objects. There are issues so the dupe does not match the "actual" question.

Comment: @JasonS - theoretically, yes.  I'm disagreeing with closing this as a dupe based on that question, not with the answer itself.  Some random older JS implementations do weird things, and even if they are all memory-bound, a one line answer saying "there is no limit" is not sufficient to close this question.  At least there should be a link to the ECMA docs.  I'm just arguing principals on closing questions here :)

Comment: Are you on the same domain with the frames? Have you add console lines to see how far down the tree you can go before it errors out? Is the parent.XXX give you want you expect to start out? You need to do some debugging.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, the frames are on the same domain. I can go up to one level abnove `Deep` before the osurce code stops working. Currently, I created a new Struct to hold `Deep` so that I can set and get its values. I was just wondering if there was an easier way, but given that it works this sounds like a memory issue.

Comment: And you are access the data after the data has been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no *inherent* limit to nested objects in Javascript that is dependent on the particular design implementation. It should depend on the amount of memory that is available to the Javascript runtime.

Javascript objects have properties. If you have a 23-level deep hierarchy `foo.bar.baz.quux[23].figaro.figaro.figaro...`, the only thing the top level object "sees" is its immediate child properties: `foo` has a property `bar` which itself is an object. The value contained in `foo.bar` does not affect `foo` in any way whatsoever. (From `foo`'s point of view, it's an object reference, like a pointer in C.) Similarly, the object `foo.bar` has a child property `baz` which itself is an object.

Please note that you can have cycles in property accesses, so technically you *can* have infinite levels of "nesting". Here's a sample in JSDB javascript shell, where objects `foo` and `bar` each have the other as a property:

```
js>foo = {}
[object Object]
js>foo.foo = foo
[object Object]
js>foo.foo.foo.foo.foo
[object Object]
js>foo = {x: 1}
[object Object]
js>bar = {y: 2}
[object Object]
js>foo.bar = bar
[object Object]
js>bar.foo = foo
[object Object]
js>foo.bar.foo.bar.foo.bar.foo.bar.foo.bar.y
2
```

These objects *cannot* be serialized in JSON because they have reference cycles.

---

If you are running into such a limit that is *not* a memory issue, it is not with the core language, but rather may be with some aspect of the object model encountered in your browser. (e.g. if the object model is implemented in C or Java and exposed to Javascript, perhaps there are errors or "quirks" in the C/Java implementation.)

Comment: + 1, If I go one level up, I can access the variables of Frame `Course` or, can access `Deep` if I make it into its own non-nested struct on frame `Course`. Definitely sounds like a memory issue.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be any limit on how far you can nest objects (or if there is it's insanely high).  This code works fine (note I tested this is in chrome):

```
var ctr=1, obj={};
while( ctr < 1000000 ){ // 1 million
    obj = obj.obj = {}; ctr++;
};
```

I have a feeling that your issue is related to the fact that you're trying to access this "from another page".  Can you post code relating to that?

Comment: Thanks, its good to know that the vairable itself isn't a problem. I editied to original question to include some additional source code. Basically I'm trying to access `Deep` from a frame that is several layers deep on th main page, and `Deep` is located in another nested frame named `Course`.

Comment: @KernelPanik - your problem is almost _certainly_ a cross-site scripting issue.  What domains are your frames on?  different ones I'm guessing?  If they're different TLDs (e.g. siteA.com vs siteB.com) you're out of luck.  If they're different sub-domains (foo.siteA.com vs bar.siteA.com), you just need some JS on each frame.

Comment: All sites are actually on the same physical server and same domain.  For example frame Course is of 'site.com/Courses/course.html', and the calling frame is on `site.com/Courses/Engine/engine.html`. I can set Deep in the Course frame alright from the Engine frame, but cannot get its value. For now, I've has to create a duplicate struct for Deep to actually store its values. Also, `Deep` is part of a very large Object. Could this possibly be a memory issue?

Comment: @KernelPanik - `www.site.com` vs `site.com`?  You generally only get `undefined` values doing this when you hit security issues.  How are you hitting the values?  `frameName.val`?  you need to hit the frame's window object first

Comment: I'm able to access other variables in the frame ok, and well as the frame name. It only seems to have an issue with deeply nested variables on the frame. However +1, as I did not know that alone, I could infinitely nest variables.